# SAP HANA CDS View Fuzzy Search not working

Tags: hana, fuzzy

I have a HDBDD defined as such, but the fuzzy search I tried using the query below doesn't work. Only maps to full text like "`Singapore`".

https://xxxxxxxx.xxx.xx.xxxxx.com/xxxxx.xsodata/LandValue?$format=json&search=singaporw

```
namespace xxx;
@Schema : 'XXX'

context fuzzysearch {

    @Catalog.tableType : #COLUMN
    entity ADDRESS {
        key id  : Integer;
        street  : String(80);
        zipCode : Integer;
        city    : String(80);
        
        @SearchIndex.text.enabled   : true
        @SearchIndex.fuzzy.enabled  : true
        country : String(80);

    };
    
    @Search.searchable: true  
    define view V_ADDRESS as select from ADDRESS as ADDRESS {  
        @EnterpriseSearch.key : true  
        ADDRESS.id,  
        
        @Search.defaultSearchElement: true  
        @Search.ranking: #HIGH  
        @Search.fuzzinessThreshold : 0.7
        ADDRESS.country 
    };  
};
```

Comment: Please provide some test data that can show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using [this](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3913240) as your base example?

Try changing your fuzzy threshold to like .8 or .87

```
https://xxxxxxxx.xxx.xx.xxxxx.com/xxxxx.xsodata/LandValue?$format=json&search=singporw
```

Now if the only country in your dataset is Singapore then you will get everything every time of course.